# tableView.reloadData() not working, possibly not being called on main thread

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with 3 sections. Right now I'm only really testing the first section which is Add Friends. I have a search bar and when I enter text, I search to see if the user exists and reload the table if it does.

From my understanding, I'm trying to add the search task to a OperationQueue so that I can cancel it if the user edits the search field.

I have confirmation that a user is able to be searched, my call is returning that user. However, when I add the user to my addFriendsSection, and refresh my tableView, nothing is happening. I'm expecting a new cell to be added with the username of the searched user.

```
class AddFriendTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    private var sectionTitles = ["Add Friends", "Added Me", "My Followers"]

    private var addFriendsSection = [User]()
    private var addedMeSection    = [FollowRequest]()
    private var myFriendsSection  = [Follower]()

    private var sections: [[Any]]!

    private var searchUserBackgroundQueue = OperationQueue()

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sections = [
            addFriendsSection,
            addedMeSection,
            myFriendsSection
        ]

        searchBar.isTranslucent = true
        searchBar.alpha = 1
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchBar.barTintColor = .clear
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }

    // User edits the search bar
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchUserBackgroundQueue.cancelAllOperations()

        addFriendsSection = []
        tableView.reloadData()

        if searchText.count >= SignupUsernameViewController.minimumUsernameLength {

            searchUserBackgroundQueue.addOperation {
                UserHandler.shared.exists(username: searchText) { (error, user) in
                    if let user = user {

                        // ATTEMPTING TO RELOAD HERE
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.addFriendsSection.append(user)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch(sectionTitles[indexPath.section]) {
        case sectionTitles[0]:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addFriendsCell", for: indexPath) as! AddFriendsCell

            cell.usernameLabel.text = addFriendsSection[indexPath.row].username

            return cell
        case sectionTitles[1]:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addedMeCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell
        case sectionTitles[2]:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myFollowersCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell
        default:
            print("AddFriendsTableViewController cellForRowAt error!")
        }

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but try moving this outside of, before, the dispatch async block: `self.addFriendsSection.append(user)`

Comment: have you tried `viewDidAppear()`?

Comment: @MikeTaverne I've tried this, no results

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans I'm confused what you mean

Comment: @Brejuro instead of `viewDidLoad()` try running that code in `viewDidAppear()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you store your new friends in the `self.addFriendsSection` array, but the `UITableViewDataSource` methods like `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` access the `sections[section].count` array.
When you are used to Objective-C, Java, C# etc., this would work fine, but in Swift, arrays are *value types* which *copy* the values.

Hence, when you initialize the `sections` array (in `viewDidLoad`), this will *copy* the values from the `addFriendsSection` array (which initially is empty), and `numberOfRows...` will return `0`. Then, after searching, you update `addFriendsSection`, but this will not influence the contents of the `sections` array, so `numberOfRows` will still return `0`.

The most quick solution would be: either

- remove the `sections` array and just work with the three distinct array
- or remove the three distinct arrays and only work with `sections`

See this **ugly** and **quick and dirty** code for the first proposal - you'll definitely have to do it much nicer, with enums, constants or something else:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
        case 0: return addFriendsSection.count
        case 1: return addedMeSection.count
        case 2: return myFriendsSection.count
        default: return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had actually thought this could be a problem when I was writing it and then completely forgot, but it makes sense now.